# How does one use the contains text syntax in xpath. I am using ruby-cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have xpath:

```
//div[@id='123']/li/a[4]
```

which has text as '2' in its html
so i wanted it to be specific like:

```
//div[@id='123']/li/a[contains text='2'] ???
```

Basically I don't want to depend on a[**4**].. not on the number but to be specific to the text so that it can be located even after the webpage is updated or modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the predicates part `[]`, you can use `text()` to retrieve the text node and `contains(,)` to test if it contains the specific text.

```
//div[@id='123']//li/a[contains(text(), '2')]
```

Here's [an example](http://www.xpathtester.com/obj/e952d94f-2c11-46b4-93b6-0565bde8676c)